# Why beforeInAppMessageDisplayed is never called?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use Braze to send in-app message notification and show customized UI to replace the UI created by Braze. But beforeInAppMessageDisplayed is never called. Below is how I done.
I added

```
Appboy.start(withApiKey: apiKey, in: application, withLaunchOptions: launchOptions, withAppboyOptions: [ ABKInAppMessageControllerDelegateKey: self ]) in func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

and also added

```
func beforeInAppMessageDisplayed(inAppMessage: ABKInAppMessage!) -> ABKInAppMessageDisplayChoice
```

in AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by putting func beforeInAppMessageDisplayed(inAppMessage: ABKInAppMessage!) -> ABKInAppMessageDisplayChoice in ABKInAppMessageControllerDelegate.

Comment: Please take some time to learn how to format code on Stack Overflow.